Tried building expo app from bare template and then Installed expo-router, When I build apk I get error Native modules required RNNScreen
I used bare bones template because I wanted to use java script in expo. But when I install expo-router and build a production apk, I get error in the app saying required native moduels RNSScreens something. why am I getting this error. Also can someone help me how should I define my main _layout.js file and do I need to put a index.js file in the root ??
enter image description here
I tried npm i react-native-screens and react-navigation/native and all. Nothing fixes the problem.

I was missing some native modules, i reinstalled all of them and it worked
